# Texture Shows Flickering / Aliasing / Moire Patterns in Godot, Despite Mipmaps

Tags: graphics, textures, godot

If I load a checkerboard texture into Godot:

[image: A plane with a perfectly rendered checkerboard material]

And stand far enough back from it, I get strange artifacts called [Moiré patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern):

[image: A plane displaying strange, shifting artifacts]

This is a well-known problem in computer graphics which appears whenever you sample a texture that has a higher resolution than the area of the screen it is being rendered onto. (See [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing) for another illustration and full explanation.)

The usage of mipmaps is a technique to eliminate this problem by making lower-resolution versions of the texture that are then used when the camera is sufficiently far away from the object. So, I went to find out how to enable this in Godot only to find out that it was already enabled by default:

[image: Settings of the material showing that mipmaps are enabled.]

Why then am I still getting aliasing? What can I do to eliminate it?

Answer (score 0):

By default, Godot selects a higher resolution mipmap than what is needed to completely eliminate aliasing. At the cost of making your materials blurrier, the aliasing can be almost entirely removed by increasing the "Texture Mipmap Bias" by one. What this does is tell Godot's rendering engine to pick the mipmap that is half the resolution of the one it would normally pick. The setting can be found as follows:

- Go to `Project > Project Settings...`.
- Enable "Advanced Settings" to the right of the search bar.
- Navigate to `Rendering > Textures` on the left.
- The setting can then be found in `Default Filters > Texture Mipmap Bias` on the right.

[image: Location of the setting in the Project Settings dialog.]

The result:

[image: Checkerboard texture viewed at a distance without artifacts, appearing a uniform grey color.]